# How to get item position in recycler adapter by item's parameter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have two Fragments. In `Fragment A` I choose item with its unique ID. In `Fragment B` I have recycler adapter that consists of those items. I would like to take item from Fragment A, and open Fragment B with recycler adapter **set to the position of chosen item**. I found that in order to open recycler adapter on specific spot, I have to use something like that `rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(positionInTheAdapter).` The question is: **can I get that position by item's id?** Or maybe there's a better way of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you

Comment: recyclerviews are managed by adapters, you're the one responsible for giving the data to the adapter and they just show views based on the data, replacing views as you scroll up or down, so not sure if you need to really be asking the recycler for this, just search through your adapter's data to find the position of the item you want. other than that, i don't really see a problem in what you're doing already.

Comment: @a_local_nobody , how would I search through adapter's data to find the position of the item?

Comment: just use indexOf or loop through your arraylist to find the item you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be passing a list of items in Fragment B. Now when you select any item in first Fragment A then all you need to do is run a loop through all list of items passed to adapter and match on which position the item id matches that position can then be passed to `rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(positionInTheAdapter)`

For more info on how to pass data among fragments you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) article.